# Replicate excel condition statement in python

Tags: pandas, dataframe, python-2.7, numpy

I'm trying to translate a If statement from excel to python.

I know that for excel, If statement we have:

`IF(logical_test, [value_if_true], [value_if_false])`

For Python I want to replicate the below excel if statement.

`AZ2 = IF(BA2<>"",IF(BB2<>"",BB2,"Blank"), IF(BO2<>"", BO2, "Blank"))`

Here AZ2,BA2,BB2,BO2 are columns in excel file and <> represents not equal in excel.

I tried using below code using np.where but it does not work? do you know what I am doing wrong?

```
 df['AZ']=np.where(df['BA'].notnull(),
 np.where(df['BB'].notnull(),df['BB'],'Blank',
 np.where(df['BO'].notnull(),df['BO'],'Blank')))
```

I get this Error when I tried executing it.

```
Type Error: where() takes at most 3 arguments (4 given)
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue comes from the bracket missing after the first `Blank` and the extra one at the end of the statement.
You can try this one :

```py
 df['AZ']=np.where(df['BA'].notnull(),
                   np.where(df['BB'].notnull(), 
                            df['BB'],
                            'Blank'),
                   np.where(df['BO'].notnull(),
                            df['BO'],
                            'Blank'))
```